# How to use longtables in a beamer environment

Tags: beamer, longtable

I have a problem when I use the `longtable` package in a `beamer` environment. This is my code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim, longtable}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newenvironment{wideitemize}{\itemize\addtolength{\itemsep}{10pt}}{\enditemize}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
        \begin{longtable}{|p{7cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
            \caption{\textit{Power test comparison}} \\ \endhead
            \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Single} \\
            \hline
            & Acceptance & Rejection\\
            \hline \hline 
            50\% of MCAR & 95.2 & 95.8 \\
            \hline
            50\% of MAR, first  & 0 & 3\\   
            \hline
            50\% of MAR, second  & 0 & 1.2\\   
            \hline
            50\% of MAR, third  & 0 & 3.4\\   
            \hline
            50\% of MAR, fourth  & 0 & 2.9\\   
            \hline \newpage \hline
            \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Mixed} \\
            \hline
            & Acceptance & Rejection\\
            \hline \hline
            40\% of MAR and 10\% of MCAR & 0 & 4.6 \\
            hline
            30\% of MAR and 20\% of MCAR & 0 & 6.9 \\
            \hline
            20\% of MAR and 30\% of MCAR & 0 & 12 \\
            \hline
            10\% of MAR and 40\% of MCAR & 0 & 24.9 \\
            \hline
            5\% of MAR and 45\% of MCAR & 0 & 50.6 \\
            \hline
            4\% of MAR and 46\% of MCAR & 0 & 57.6 \\
            \hline
            3\% of MAR and 47\% of MCAR & 1.8 & 71.1 \\
            \hline
            2\% of MAR and 48\% of MCAR & 31.4 & 82.6 \\
            \hline
            1\% of MAR and 49\% of MCAR & 82.8 & 92.4 \\
            \hline
            \end{longtable}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Latex says that there are different error types :

- Undefined control sequence
- Use of `\LT@array` doesn't match its definition.
- Argument of `\beamer@sortzeroread` has an extra `}`.
- Paragraph ended before `\beamer@sortzeroread` was complete.
- Missing `\endcsname` inserted.

Can you please help me? What should I do knowing that I don't want to redo everything by using a simple table, because I need this size for my table parts. Moreover, I would like to have the possibility of cutting the `longtable` in different frames.

Comment: I doubt this could work without a lot of effort (unless someone has already done it and made a package)  beamer is designed for no automatic page breaking with the `allowframebreaks` as a get out clause to allow something, so it has a different output routine longtable also uses a differemt output routine but has to make some assumptions about the current one to hand over at the changes. Really in a beamer presentation in 999 times out of a 1000 you want to manually control the breaks, just add `\end{tabular}\end{frame}\begin{frame}\begin{tabular}{....}` at each point where you want a break.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt this could work without a lot of effort (unless someone has already done it and made a package) beamer is designed for no automatic page breaking with the `\allowframebreaks` as a get out clause to allow something, so it has a different output routine, longtable also uses a different output routine but has to make some assumptions about the current one to hand over at the changes. Really in a beamer presentation in 999 times out of a 1000 you want to manually control the breaks, just add

```
\end{tabular}\end{frame}\begin{frame}\begin{tabular}{....}
```

at each point where you want a break.